# How to walk through json response?

Tags: jquery, json, api

I have this json response and I'm trying to walke thought it to get the weather conditions such as "humidity" and "temp_C" and so on. I tried some ways but didn't work.

```
({ "data" : { "current_condition" : [ { "cloudcover" : "50",
            "humidity" : "44",
            "observation_time" : "12:10 AM",
            "precipMM" : "0.0",
            "pressure" : "1013",
            "temp_C" : "-2",
            "temp_F" : "29",
            "visibility" : "16",
            "weatherCode" : "116",
            "weatherDesc" : [ { "value" : "Partly Cloudy" } ],
            "weatherIconUrl" : [ { "value" : "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0004_black_low_cloud.png" } ],
            "winddir16Point" : "W",
            "winddirDegree" : "280",
            "windspeedKmph" : "24",
            "windspeedMiles" : "15"
          } ],
      "request" : [ { "query" : "Rochester, United States Of America",
            "type" : "City"
          } ],
      "weather" : [ { "date" : "2012-02-25",
            "precipMM" : "2.2",
            "tempMaxC" : "-1",
            "tempMaxF" : "31",
            "tempMinC" : "-5",
            "tempMinF" : "24",
            "weatherCode" : "116",
            "weatherDesc" : [ { "value" : "Partly Cloudy" } ],
            "weatherIconUrl" : [ { "value" : "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals.png" } ],
            "winddir16Point" : "W",
            "winddirDegree" : "281",
            "winddirection" : "W",
            "windspeedKmph" : "54",
            "windspeedMiles" : "34"
          } ]
    } })
```

I tried these:

```
$.getJSON(urlFromMyAPI, function (data) {
    alert(data.current_condition.temp_C);
    alert(data.temp_C);
    alert(data[current_condition].temp_C);
    // I also use loop
    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        alert(data.current_condition[i])
    }
});
};
```

Comment: is that data in your data, or what did you paste?

Comment: Not sure I got your question, but this data is what comes back from the world weather online api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your main issue is that your data is nested inside an object named `data` so you need an extra level of reference to get inside it.  It's also a lot easier to see what you've got when you format your response like this so you can see the nested objects and arrays more clearly:

```
({ "data": { 
    "current_condition": [ 
        {
            "cloudcover": "50", 
            "humidity": "44", 
            "observation_time": "12:10 AM", 
            "precipMM": "0.0", 
            "pressure": "1013", 
            "temp_C": "-2", 
            "temp_F": "29", 
            "visibility": "16", 
            "weatherCode": "116",  
            "weatherDesc": [ 
                {"value": "Partly Cloudy" } 
            ],  
            "weatherIconUrl": [ 
                {"value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0004_black_low_cloud.png" } 
            ], 
            "winddir16Point": "W", 
            "winddirDegree": "280", 
            "windspeedKmph": "24", 
            "windspeedMiles": "15" 
        } 
    ],  
    "request": [ 
        {"query": "Rochester, United States Of America", "type": "City" } 
    ],  
    "weather": [
        {
            "date": "2012-02-25", 
            "precipMM": "2.2", 
            "tempMaxC": "-1", 
            "tempMaxF": "31", 
            "tempMinC": "-5", 
            "tempMinF": "24", 
            "weatherCode": "116",  
            "weatherDesc": [ 
                {"value": "Partly Cloudy" } 
            ],  
            "weatherIconUrl": [
                {"value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals.png" } 
            ], 
            "winddir16Point": "W", 
            "winddirDegree": "281", 
            "winddirection": "W", 
            "windspeedKmph": "54", 
            "windspeedMiles": "34" 
        } 
    ] 
}
})
```

That said, if you want to get the current condition `temp_C`, it would be like this (note I changed the argument name for your anonymous function to make the code less confusing):

```
$.getJSON( urlFromMyAPI, function(response){
    var temp = response.data.current_condition[0].temp_C;
});
```

If you want the temp as a number, you may need to do this:

```
$.getJSON( urlFromMyAPI, function(response){
    var temp = parseInt(response.data.current_condition[0].temp_C, 10);
});
```

Comment: It works buddy. Could not give you +1 i have no reputation :)

Comment: @user1233225 - after the appropriate amount of time has passed, you can press the checkmark next to your favorite answer to mark it as the best answer and you will also get some reputation points for that.

Answer (score 1):

To loop through the array contained inside the `JSON` object you need to access `data.data.current_condition`:

```
for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
   alert(data.data.current_condition[i]);

   var properties = data.data.current_condition[i];

   for(var y in properties)
       alert(properties[y]);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m7TZx/

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code.

1. Your variable is called data, and the first thing in the JSON is an object called data.
2. current_condition is an array of object (in Javascript, square brackets `[]` refer to an array, curly braces `{}` refer to an object), so you must say current_condition[index] before referring to temp_C.

I renamed `data` to `json_data` in this example to avoid confusion:

```
$.getJSON( urlFromMyAPI, function(json_data){
    console.log(json_data.data.current_condition[0].temp_C);
});
```

If you have multiple `current_condition` objects you can use a for loop to go through them:

```
$.getJSON( urlFromMyAPI, function(json_data){
    var current_conditions = json_data.data.current_condition;
    for(var i=0; i < current_conditions.length; i++) {
        console.log(current_conditions.temp_C);
    }
});
```

You can use a Javascript beautifier (e.g. http://jsbeautifier.org/) if you want to see it in a better format.

You might find `console.log` to be more useful than `alert`. Most browsers have a console, in Google Chrome you can find it by pressing `F12` and clicking console.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON shouldn't be wrapped in "()" except when it is sent as jsonp with a function name before opening "(". For now will assume you copied response from a browser pointing at the jsonp url and what is pasted is a copy error.

Using $.each makes the looping very easy.

```
$.each( data.data.current_condition[0], function ( key, value){
    console.log( 'Key:', key, ' Value:', value)
})
```