# Jackson - binding first array member to object using annotations

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, unmarshalling

As you could see from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449638/how-to-walk-through-json-response) question, the response that worldweather return is not quite pretty. They return array of current weather conditions (I try to understand why did they made it that way, there couldn't be more then one weather condition in a specific place, as far as I know...), so it breaks the unmarshalling via annotations,

```
@JsonProperty("current_condition")
private CurrentWeatherData currentWeatherData;
```

because Jackson actually awaits a collection or an array. Now, can I somehow to tell the unmarshaller to use the first array member, and if yes, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such annotation. You will probably want a custom deserializer to handle this special case.

For Jackson 2.2 there will be support for separate `Converter`s, which could work here (as they only work on Java objects). But since it is not yet released, custom deserializer is probably the way to go.